# Drupal and Ubercart: how to add fields to attributes?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'm building an e-commerce app using Drupal 6 and Ubercart module.
For some single products, I need to handle variants like color and size and every single size/color needs single custom attributes like subcode and others.
Which is the best way to build those items? I think to use Ubercart Attributes but I don't know if it's possible to add custom fields to attributes. Is it possible without modifying the core? At this moment I'm adding CCK attributes to `content_type_product` and by adding `parent_node` referred node but I don't like too much this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Flexi fields](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) module. But however I have not tried this in conjunction with UberCart. Please let me know if that works fine. Might come handy in future.